# Magento 2: Block/Remove customer/section/load compare products ajax call

Tags: magento, magento2

I have removed compare product functionality by adding below code in my theme's default.xml file.

\app\design\frontend\\default\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
```

But in my website still compare products ajax call is getting triggered in all the pages.

```
http://local.website.com/customer/section/load/?sections=compare-products%2Ccart&update_section_id=true&_=1513311940895
```

Can you please let me know how to block this ajax call?

Answer (score -1):

You also need to add this code into your `default.xml` file.

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
     <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I did static deployment & complete cache flush. But still no luck